# C# Connect to mobile network using 4G Dongle APN

Tags: c#, .net, 4g, dotras

I'm developing a custom application that enable a user to connect to internet via a USB Mobile 4G Dongle.

The problem is I was able only to connect to 3G network by dail the number *99# using DotRas.dll library

Code Snippet, connecting using a pre-defined Windows connection dailup

```
private void ConnectRas(string entryName)
{
    try
    {
        var x = RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.User);
        var path = File.Exists(x) ? x : @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
            return;

        RasConnection conn = RasConnection.GetActiveConnections().FirstOrDefault(o => o?.EntryName == entryName);
        var state = conn?.GetConnectionStatus().ConnectionState;

        if (state == RasConnectionState.Connected)
            return;

        using (var dialer = new RasDialer())
        {
            dialer.EntryName = entryName;
            dialer.PhoneBookPath = path;
            //dialer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Password");
            dialer.Dial();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.GetLogger().Error(e, e.Message);
    }
}
```

I need to be able to enter APN hostname, username, password directly from C# and connect to 4G network and not 3G.

Please help. thank you